# Setting up UIScrollview and autolayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios7

I created a UIScrollview and added a few UIElements to it, it works without autolayout no problem, scrolls etc. However its good practice to use autolayout in iOS7. Now the scrollview does not scroll. How do I accomodate for this?

If I turn auto layout off, there is extra space added to the top of the uiscrollview in ios7.

I used to set up the scrollview by 'unchecking' autolayout and implementing the following code.

```
//to set up the scrollview
[self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 800)];
```

which worked. But using autolayout prevents scrolling. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right way to do it. Put a scroll view in the view controller, set x and y 0, make height bigger than screens view, e.g 1500. Place a view in the scrollview, set its x and y to 0, set its height a little less than that of the scrollview, eg 1200. Then pin this view to the scrollview. The button for pinning is [image] and is found in the storyboard. This worked for me like a charm. The scrollview does not need to have its coordinates set in the .m file.

This worked.